# javascript onclick scroll to div on middle page but with button

Tags: javascript

when i press the button "continue"  , but i need with button

problem with that `https://jsfiddle.net/ytgu1fbo/7/` , i dont know where can put the button image

`https://gyazo.com/c5c62db350d09245e30e7452c0cb3362` example on internet

When i clicked the button , like continue button , go to middle page

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="color: rgb(188, 52, 21); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;" onclick="scroll_to_contact_form_fn()">Click here</span>


<script>
function scroll_to_contact_form_fn() {
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;
  var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
    console.log(height);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: height/2 - window.innerHeight/2
    }, 200);
}
</script>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="myForm" style="width: 100%; height: 30px; background: red;">
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: you want to turn span into a button?

Comment: The snippet is doing what you need. What exactly you want?

Comment: I want when i clicked the button "continue" , example in image, go the middle page. Same that script but with button

Comment: And idk what need to change

Comment: Just replace the span to a button: https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=d1348ec3-ef52-4bed-a07d-c8ac36889449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<span>` tag with `<img>` tag will give the image button you want by specifying the dimensions.

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="Click here" height="<px>" width="<px>" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="scroll_to_contact_form_fn()" />
```

Comment: I still have a doubt?
You want a button in "myForm" div?

Comment: its possible to change with image button ? my image ? Thanks u

Comment: updated the answer; please replace src with your image file; height and weight for your suitable size.

Comment: and when i have 2 button in 1 ? like effect when is cursor on this one , how can do  ?

Comment: i want like this: https://gyazo.com/2a51d7ebbb592c2308e653444fe7953a , i have the buttons , and with that code not showing the continue text